# PRTG sensor displaying if "change logon /q" is true/false - Batch-file/Powershell-file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, prtg

Im not a professional programmer, so please excuse any mistakes I do with terms & co.
I want to build a custom sensor for PRTG that displays whether logging in on my terminal server is possible or not. PRTG offers the possibility of using Batch-files or Powershell-files.
My first thought was

```
change logon /q
```

cause this does perfectly display what I want to know. But I don't know how to get this working. It seems like I have problem with the return value, I think I need a return like:

```
value:message
```

Maybe this helps:

[image: A description of PRTG for custom sensors]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Per the guidance you shared you need to return a value code and a message separated by a colon. Try this a a PowerShell script:

```
$Result = change logon /q
Return "0:$Result"
```

Comment: We can add logic to this so the sensor errors if rdp is not enabled. Just out at lunch but will edit when I’m back.

Comment: Well at least it doesnt show any error. But logic would be nice, as for now I only get 0 which equals OK

Comment: Its worth also noting that this sensor will run on the PRTG probe and so return the result of the probe. If you want to be able to remotely query this value for other machines you need some way for PowerShell to remotely execute the command from the Probe server -- e.g via WinRM or similar.

Comment: Im new to PRTG so Im just guessing what you exactly mean. So I have to install PRTG with the script on the server? If I have the script only on my local pc (and PRTG) it wouldnt work?

Answer (score 0):

If it is purely the exit code required, then in batch this should work:

```
change logon /q
echo %errorlevel%
```

You can then translate it by building a list:

```
change logon /q
goto :%errorlevel
:0
echo 0:Ok
goto :eof
:1
echo 1:Warning
goto :eof
:2
echo 2:System Error
goto :eof
:3
echo 3:Protocol Error
goto :eof
:4
echo 4:Content Error
goto :eof
```

Where the above list is just a small example.

Comment: Sounds really good, but I get the Error by PRTG that I doesnt know the command "change". It says I either typed it wrong or it couldnt be found

Comment: The exact error-code is in german. I simply put your code in a .bat-File and added it as a sensor on PRTG.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an answer, for everyone who maybe has the same problem.

```
gwmi win32_terminalservicesetting -N "root\cimv2\terminalservices" | %{
if ($_.logons -eq 1){
"Disabled"}
Else {
switch ($_.sessionbrokerdrainmode)
{
0 {"Enabled"}
1 {"DrainUntilRestart"}
2 {"Drain"}
default {"something’s not right here!"}
}
}
}
```

This code equals "change logon /query

Source: [Link](http://andrewmorgan.ie/2012/08/using-powershell-as-a-replacement-for-the-change-logon-command-in-remote-desktop-services/)